# Docker with an Apache is restarting in a loop

Tags: apache, loops, docker, docker-compose, restart

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 which run an app supported by Docker (version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be) and docker-compose (version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21). One of this dockers contains an Apache which is restating in a loop.

Is there a way to fix this without losing dockers customizations?

[image: docker px]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-created all dockers with

> docker-compose up --force-recreate

I didn't lose anything and everything is working now.